# How do I check if two std::vector's contain only the same elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector, comparison

I need an algorithm or a standard library function for comparing two vector elements, like below:

```
class Utility
{
    template <class T>
    static bool CheckIfVectorsEquivalent(   const std::vector<T> & Vec1,
                                            const std::vector<T> & Vec2)
    {
        // ???
    }
};
```

Working under the following specifications:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8;

// Returns false when not all the elements are matching between vectors
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(3);
v1.push_back(5);
v2.push_back(2);
v2.push_back(3);
v2.push_back(8);
Utility::CheckIfVectorsEquivalent(v1, v2);  // Must return false

// Returns true when all the elements match, even if the are not in the same order
v3.push_back(3);
v3.push_back(1);
v3.push_back(7);
v4.push_back(7);
v4.push_back(3);
v4.push_back(1);
Utility::CheckIfVectorsEquivalent(v3, v4);  // Must return true

// Returns false when one of the vectors is subset of the other one
v5.push_back(3);
v5.push_back(1);
v5.push_back(7);
v6.push_back(7);
v6.push_back(3);
v6.push_back(1);
v6.push_back(18);
v6.push_back(51);
Utility::CheckIfVectorsEquivalent(v5, v6);  // Must return false

// Returns true when the both vectors are empty
Utility::CheckIfVectorsEquivalent(v7, v8);  // Must return true
```

Is there any standard (with STL) way of doing this? If not, how can I write this algorithm? It confused me too much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard way will be **sorting these two vectors and using operator `==`**, which compares corresponding values.

The sample solution realizing this algorithm is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
bool compare(std::vector<T>& v1, std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    return v1 == v2;
}
```

Its complexity is O(n*log(n)), because of the sorting.

Comment: Doing a O(n^2) comparison might be faster for very small sets, but only for small sets. This answer is accurate for 99% of the time.

Comment: "It is also the fastest possible algorithm" Proof?

Comment: Not using sets or other things like that, but simply sorting vectors comes from my experience. From the complexity point of view this is O(n log n). That means, you have (without any other assumptions) to recognize `n!` different vectors as equal, and the size of that decision tree is `log(n!) = Omega(n log n)`. More precise proof can be done similarily to the sorting lower bound.

Comment: @RafałRawicki: Sorting routine have "N log N" **average** complexity. Depending on input data, you can hit worst case complexity, in which case something else will work much faster. I'd recommend to remove "the fastest possible" part. It is misleading.

Comment: @SigTerm There are O(N log N) worst-case sorts.

Comment: Actually std::sort is worst case O(N log N), probably implemented as IntroSort. See C++ standard [25.4.1.1].

Comment: @AlanStokes: And there are O(N) best case sorts. As I said "the fastest possible" is not a guarantee and IMO should be removed.

Comment: For the general case, you can't bucket sort.  That's fairly obvious.  What if T were a vector<DigitType> that represented a bignum (for example).  I wouldn't focus on that sentence too much for problems with the answer.  However, the answer isn't really an answer since class T could easily be equality testable without having an order.

Comment: @SigTerm, okay, you have what you wanted.

Comment: @SigTerm: It's still not an answer for the general problem, since most types T don't have orders and only require equality testing for the problem to make sense.

Comment: @RafałRawicki: Did you just get bullied into changing one wrong answer into another, worse answer?  Your answer still only makes sense with an order, but now you've removed an interesting (and correct) comment on complexity in that case.

Comment: @ex0du5: "It's still not" write a better answer. Comment on complexity was not correct, because it was implementation-dependent, data-order dependent, and data-type dependent. Unless, of course, you can prove (using C++ standard) that in ALL possible scenarios for ALL possible datatypes for ALL possible alternative algorithms the statement was correct.

Comment: @SigTerm: I don't need to write a better answer because Marshall Clow wrote a correct answer (which I commented on).  And it didn't state which algorithm to use, it said it provided the best complexity in the general case.  It was only wrong to assume order, but in ordered objects, that statement was correct - in the general case.

Comment: @ex0du5: Look, if you want a discussion, discuss somewhere else - I'm not in the mood. SO is QA, and I think my reasoning was sound. End of discussion.

Comment: Great answer and with no risks. In the event of having a type without order the code will not compile. So just use the alternative (with worse performance) in that case. Best performance indeed.

Answer (score 21):

If you can live with just a c++11 solution, then [`std::is_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) is exactly what you want

```
template <class FI1, class FI2>
bool is_permutation ( FI1 first, FI1 last, FI2 d_first );
```

If you can't do that, then in the upcoming boost 1.50 release, there will be

```
boost::algorithm::is_permutation
```

with the same interface.

Comment: Standard says, that std::is_permutation, compares elements at most O(n^2), so this is probably slower, but it's short to write.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, as it doesn't make assumptions of order on the type T.

Comment: Definitely O(N^2) in the worst case, but it uses no additional memory.

Comment: @RafałRawicki It's the only solution that assumes `T` only has `==` defined plus uses O(1) memory. If `T` can be sorted, you can decide if O(n) memory is acceptable for better time complexity (using a `std::map` of counts, `std::sort` on copies (if copy is defined), etc.). If a hash is defined for `T`, an O(n) time and space algorithm is to map to counts. Add 1 for each occurrence for  the first vector, subtract one for the second vector. If all values in the map are 0, it's true. Otherwise, false.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `multiset` from each vector, then just compare them for equality.

Answer (score 0):

There's an O(n) solution to this problem for unsorted inputs:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

template <typename T>
T xorfunc(const T& a, const T& b) {
  return a^b;
}

template <typename T>
bool compare(const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2) {
  if (v1.size() != v2.size())
    return false;

  T result = 0;
  std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), boost::make_function_output_iterator([&result](const T& r) { result ^= r; }), std::ptr_fun(&xorfunc<T>));
  return !result;
}
```

that works for integer inputs and exploits the fact that `a ^ b ^ c ^ d == 0` for any combination of paired values. It will never give false negatives, it *might* give false positives potentially, but you can reduce those further in O(n) space/time. If you're mostly hitting negatives then this might be useful as a pre-sort+compare step to rule them out quickly. It works for all the test cases you've shown:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8;

    // Returns false when not all the elements are matching between vectors
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(5);
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(8);
    std::cout << compare(v1, v2) << " (false)" << std::endl;  // Must return false

    // Returns true when all the elements match, even if the are not in the same order
    v3.push_back(3);
    v3.push_back(1);
    v3.push_back(7);
    v4.push_back(7);
    v4.push_back(3);
    v4.push_back(1);
    std::cout << compare(v3, v4) << " (true)" << std::endl;  // Must return true

    // Returns false when one of the vectors is subset of the other one
    v5.push_back(3);
    v5.push_back(1);
    v5.push_back(7);
    v6.push_back(7);
    v6.push_back(3);
    v6.push_back(1);
    v6.push_back(18);
    v6.push_back(51);
    std::cout << compare(v5, v6) << " false" << std::endl;  // Must return false

    // Returns true when the both vectors are empty
    std::cout << compare(v7, v8) << " true" << std::endl;  // Must return true

}
```

Gives:

```
0 (false)
1 (true)
0 false
1 true
```

Comment: If they are sorted already, you can just use `operator==` on vectors.

Comment: How is `mismatch` an improvement on straight equality after sorting?

Comment: The iterator it gives you tells you where the difference lies which may/may not be of interest

Comment: @awoodland: "The iterator it gives you tells you where the difference lies" Wasn't a part of original question/request, so that's not an improvement.

Comment: Changed my solution completely - it's now the only O(n) solution out there.

Comment: @awoodland There are cases where this returns true incorrectly.

Comment: @awoodland It can be done in constant time if you don't need the answer to be right.

Comment: @awoodland: Judging from a quick glance, you want to xor all elements and expect to get zero if they're all equal, right? Here's the problem: `Vec1[0, 12]; Vec2[4, 8]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it is to create copies of Vec1 and Vec2, sort them and compare using `==`.

Another way to do it is to build two multisets from Vec1 and Vec2 and compare them using `==`.

Yet another way to do it is to use maps (std::map or unordered_map) to store counters - i.e. increment stored value for every element of Vec1 and decrement for every stored element of Vec2, then check if map contains non-zero elements. If there are non-zero elements stored in map, vectors are non-equal.

messy pseudocode example:

```
std::vector<Value> vec1, vec2;
//initialize vec1 and vec2, fill with data
typedef int Counter;
typedef unordered_map<Value, Counter> CounterMap;

CounterMap counters;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)
    counters[vec1[i]]++;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec2.size(); i++)
    counters[vec2[i]]--;

bool equal = true;
for (CounterMap::const_iterator i = coutners.begin(); equal && (i != counters.end()); i++)
    if (i->second != 0)
        equal = false;
```

Depending on your STL (or boost) implementation, data type, and order of stored data in vectors) one of those methods will be faster, but it is hard to tell which one.

Comment: Equality comparison of unordered multisets is worst-case O(N^2), so probably worth avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider an int to be large enough for the computations done in the following algorithm, there is a simple O(N) algorithm.

0: initialization: There are primes to the size of max(v1,v2), product1=1, product2=1

1: return false if size of v1 != size of v2

2:

```
foreach (  i in v1 ) {
   product1 *= primes[v1[i]]
   product2 *= primes[v2[i]]
}
```

3.

```
result product1 == product2;
```

Comment: You only need `std::size(v1)` number of primes since you would only do the multiplication if the vectors are the same size. `i in v1` is incorrect since those semantics seem like `i` takes on the values in `v1`. Pseudocode might be `i in range(0, size(v1) - 1)`. The algorithm is interesting, but it will stop working sooner than other algorithms if there are enough elements due to overflow. If you use arbitrary precision integers, multiplication takes more than a single instruction, increasing time complexity beyond linear. Note this algorithm also takes O(n) memory to store the primes.

Comment: Additionally, the problem statement is after a solution for two vectors holding type `T`. Multiplication may not be overloaded, or it might do something unexpected when multiplied by a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
  v7.push_back(3);
  v7.push_back(1);
  v7.push_back(7);

  v8.push_back(7);
  v8.push_back(3);
  v8.push_back(1);
  v8.push_back(1);
  v8.push_back(7);

  std::cout << compare(v7, v8) << " true or false" << std::endl;
```

the condition as above, the function compare will return true or false.I lost count.
if return true.
we can't use the way:
The standard way will be sorting these two vectors and using operator ==, which compares corresponding values.